# Having values as keys VS having them as a nested object array in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack

Currently , I have a elasticsearch index with a field that has subfields like say A,B,C as below:

```
"myfield":{
  "A":{
    "name":"A",
    "prop1":{
      "sub-prop1":1,
      "sub-prop2":2
   },
    "prop2":{}
 },
  "B":{
    "name":"B",
    "prop1":{
      "sub-prop1":3,
      "sub-prop2":8,
      "sub-prop3":4,
      "sub-prop4":7,
   },
    "prop2":{}
 },
  "C":{}
}
```

As can be seen, the structure of A and B fields are same, but the sub-props under the prop1 can be dynamic , meaning based on the documents added, the mapping might change but its not an issue as A and B exist as separate keys.However, because of this I am facing another problem, in that keeping on adding new documents, due to dynamic mapping, its possible that such sub-props or sub-fields like A,B,C,D ... and so on keep getting added to the mapping, which in turn might cause the mapping to  exceed the **index.mapping.total_fields.limit** ,so to avoid that I am planning to make "myfield" and "prop1" fields as array of objects instead in the mapping, so that the fields A,B,C... are stored as array elements instead of keep getting added to the mapping as new fields.

The question is - is this a feasible solution and how to search for say, "myfield.A.prop1.sub-prop1" >= 3

the new mapping looks something like:

```
"myfield":[
  {
    "name":"A",
    "prop1":{
      "sub-prop1":1,
      "sub-prop2":2
   },
    "prop2":{}
 },
 {
    "name":"B",
    "prop1":{
      "sub-prop1":3,
      "sub-prop2":8,
      "sub-prop3":4,
      "sub-prop4":7,
   },
    "prop2":{}
 },
 {}
]
```

Comment: Why not store these in seperate documents? Do you have querry with condition on A.X and B.X or you only query name by name, so independently ? With your current modelisation you will have performance issue.

Comment: the fields A, B, C ... are attributes that may be present in any document.At present they are added as keys under "myfield" and hence the mapping gets bigger everytime a new field is encountered in a new document( say having A,C, D). To avoid that, I am looking for something generic like an object array,so that it can hold any new field without changing the mapping.But this way, I am not sure how to perform searches across all array elements(for A,B,C...)

Comment: If myfield is nested field, the search will be ok (second mapping). For more help we have to know the number max of fields (searchable) you expect in each document, their size, and how you want to querry them. According to that, a parent-child model, or a different representation (starting by prop for example, using dictionnay). If you only have number in sub-prop, i wont add fields in sub-prop part for example, but another nested field.

Comment: If you dont have X different mappings for the props fields, you can use something like that to store them as a nested sublist. Should be cleaner and faster (as you wont have to add 48984 fields in your mappings for sub-prop but only 5-6).
"prop": [
 "name_prop":,
 "type_prop":,
 "value_int":,
 "value_str":,
 "value_datetime":,
 ...
]

Comment: Yes, I went through some documentation over the weekend and decided to use nested types for these fields too.Thanks for the suggestion.